# lattice xyplot 3x3 arrangement

Tags: matrix, lattice

I have 3 xyplots from lattice. Up to now I have only ever used

```
print(pd1, split = c(1,1,2,2), more = TRUE)
```

`print(pd2, split = c(2, 1, 2, 2), more = TRUE)` etc (using split) 
to arrange plots in 2x2 manner. However, how can I use it for 1x3 or 3x3 arrangement? I tried to do some positions but I have not quite understood how it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

```
# I think this is what you want

data <- data.frame(class = LETTERS[1:6], value = 1:6)

pd1 <- dotplot(value ~ class, data)
pd2 <- dotplot(class ~ value, data)
pd3 <- dotplot(class ~ value | cut(value, c(0, 3, 6)), data)

print(pd1, split = c(1, 1, 1, 3), more = TRUE)
print(pd2, split = c(1, 2, 1, 3), more = TRUE)
print(pd1, split = c(1, 3, 1, 3))
```